# i want to create a common regex function for AB 1111, A.B 1111,A.B.C. 1111 and A.B. 1111

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I tried using

```
(\D+)[^/](\D+)[\s](\d+)
```

but I'm not able to exclude the forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^[A-Z](?:\.?[A-Z])*\.?\s\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xVXocP/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?:\.?[A-Z])*` - 0 or more occurrences of an optional `.` and then an uppercase ASCII letter
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.